# IF function keeps returning generic error message

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to build a dashboard in Excel that pulls data from a separate xlsx that is generated by a Python script. Right now, I want the dashboard to take a user specified date, display data from the Python-generated xlsx that corresponds to that date, and then chart said data. Using `INDEX(MATCH())` functions I am able to extract the data; however, now I am encountering a persistent error with the `IF` function. I want to nest the `INDEX(MATCH())` functions in an `IF` function so that empty cells in the source data aren't copied over as zeros, but no matter what I do with the `IF` function I get the generic error pop-up.

`=A1=A1` returns `True`;
`=IF(A1=A1)` returns the error pop-up.

I think I may have caused settings I am unaware to change at some point. Because Python defaults to exporting to General format, I had to force the user specified date cell to be text format. I think Excel might now be confused by what is and isn't text. I am also looking into how to have Python export the date column as an Excel-formatted date, so that the user entered date no longer needs to be text.

Update: I found that `=IF(A1=A1,True,False)` works, and `=IF(A1=A1,)` returns 0 instead of the error. I'm going to leave this thread open, because the second and third arguments in the `IF` function are suppose to be optional.

Comment: Does comparing the values converted to TEXT work?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik In the Index(Match()) function? Yes. After converting the user-entered date to text, the function works as intended. In IF functions? No. I've tried various combinations of text, date, numeric formats as well as using quotations and ampersands.

Comment: This question from stackoverflow might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289945/why-is-the-syntax-for-a-worksheet-if-function-with-optional-parameters-differe